# phpseclib - Entering value to prompt

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I can't find examples related to this problem.
I want to enter values to prompt that comes after I send a command

I send this command:

```
$ssh->exec('sudo pure-pw useradd '.$server_dir.' -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/'.$server_dir);
```

and it should return a prompt if using putty. It's not the sudo password (i've disabled password prompt for user). The password prompt is for a ftp user.

```
Password:
```

after that:

```
Enter it again:
```

I was wondering, how could I answer them with phpseclib?
I tried:

```
$ssh-exec('password');
$ssh-exec('password');
```

but it doesn't work, so I'm kind of stuck now.

edit//
I also tried using read and write, but the page keeps on loading forever..

Answer (score 3):

Okay so finally I got it working, here's the code:

```
$ssh->write('sudo pure-pw useradd '.$server_dir.' -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/'.$server_dir."\r\n");
$ssh->read("Password:");
$ssh->write($ftp_pw."\r\n");
$ssh->read("Enter it again:");
$ssh->write($ftp_pw."\r\n");
$ssh->exec("sudo pure-pw mkdb");
```

Comment: After you do that last write I, personally, think you'd probably be better off doing `$ssh->read('prompt')` and then doing `$ssh->write('sudo ...')`. But if what you're doing works then that works too lol.